# How to check services(mysql running or not) in remote server without login from the local server. We don't have login access to the remote server

Tags: mysql, monitoring, sql-scripts

How to check services(mysql running or not) in remote server without login from the local server. We don't have login access to the remote server.

I tried with mysqladmin command but getting below error

mysqladmin --host=localhost:3306  --user=admin status
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost:3306' failed
error: 'Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running on localhost:3306 and that the port is 3306.

Any other option we have to full fill the requirement
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look once to get an answer [here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont have server ssh Access , Hence you are not able to check Weather your MYSQL serveices are running or not on remote server.

Still you can check it using PHP code if you have access to FTP of filesystem

```
<?php
 echo exec("ps aux | grep mysql");
 echo phpinfo();
 exit;
?>
```

If your Mysql services are running than you will get output like below with some other process ids

```
   www-data  8476  0.0  0.0  11288   940 ?        S    12:29   0:00 grep mysql
```

However to actually connect with Remote Mysql server you need below things

1. Remote Mysql Server Hostname and Port
2. Mysql Database Username
3. Mysql database password
4. Of course mysql database name itself

Than only you can connect with it within your script.
All above can work on CLI also if you have server IP / User access

Hope this helps you.